# Using Oauth with GuzzleHttp and Magento API in PHP

Tags: php, magento, rest, oauth, guzzle

I'm trying to access Magento's REST API in PHP, using Oauth and GuzzleHttp.

I'm basing my example off of this Twitter example:
https://github.com/guzzle/oauth-subscriber

My code so far is:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Subscriber\Oauth\Oauth1;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client(array(
        'base_url' => 'http://magento',
        'defaults' => array('auth' => 'oauth')
    ));

    $oauth = new Oauth1(array(
        'consumer_key'    => 'magento_key',
        'consumer_secret' => 'magento_secret'
    ));


    $client->getEmitter()->attach($oauth);

    $response = $client->post('/oauth/initiate');

    print_r($response);die();
```

My host is `http://magento`. I'm trying to POST my key and secret to `/oauth/initiate` like is says in the Magento docs.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html#OAuthAuthentication-AuthenticationEndpoints

Does anyone have any insight on what I might be doing wrong? I'm getting a 500 error using Firefox's RESTClient to make this call.

**EDIT:**
I'm now getting this exception thrown

```
{
"response": "Client error response [url] http://magento/oauth/initiate [status code] 400 [reason phrase] Bad Request"
}
```

It's getting a 400 from `http://magento/oauth/initiate` but this is only when using GuzzleHttp and Oauth. If I make the POST directly within RESTClient as `http://magento/oauth/initiate`, I get an error response from Magento itself (so it does not 400), and if I add all the necessary params I get the appropriate token responses.

**UPDATE:**
After inspecting the exception being thrown I'm seeing my authorization array does not conain my callback url. This is suppose to be `http://magento/oauth/authorize` which I've adde in the RESTClient and it works with the token response. Iv'e tried adding this in my `$oauth` array as `'callback'` and `'oauth_callback'` but neither seem to work. I can see this appears in the exception, under my data array, but not in the [authorize] array which I believe it needs to be. I tihnk that's what's missing, if someone has an idea of where it needs to be placed.